# My POS application is inserting records twice into the database

Tags: php, mysql, loops, version

I have been trying to insert into my database but it inserts with a random behavior. Although, the code runs correctly on **PHP Version 7.**, I'm having problems with running it on **PHP Version 8.1.2**.

Sometimes it inserts correctly, most times it inserts twice. That's my only challenge actually. I also tried to fix by reporting errors using || ob_start(); ini_set('display_errors', 1); || and also disabled the javascript alert but no error was displayed. I'd appreciate it if you could look at the code a little closer. I checked the error logs and there's no problem.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_sales'])){
    $prd = $_POST['prd'];
    $count = count($prd);
    $rand_sales = rand(); 
    $cust_name = check_input($_POST['custname']);
    $cust_num = check_input($_POST['custnumber']);
    // echo $count;
    // Looping all files
    if($count<1){
        // $error = 'Cart is empty';
        echo '<script>alert("Cart is empty !!!");window.location="all_products.php";</script>';
        // echo '<script>window.location="all_products.php";</script>';
        
    }else{
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            $products = $_POST['prd'][$i];
            $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
            $qty = $_POST['qty'][$i];
            
                  $fl= dbconnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO sales SET cust_name=:custname, cust_number=:custnumber, prd_name=:prd, qty=:qty, price=:price, ref_code=:random");
                  $fl->bindParam(':custname', $cust_name);
                  $fl->bindParam(':custnumber', $cust_num);
                  $fl->bindParam(':prd', $products);
                  $fl->bindParam(':qty', $qty);
                  $fl->bindParam(':price', $price);
                  $fl->bindParam(':random', $rand_sales);
                  $fl->execute();
        }
        if($fl){
            echo "<script>alert('doneit');window.location='all_products.php';</script>";
          }else {
            echo "<script>alert('Error Inserting Into Database')</script>";
          }
          
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "random behavior" and "having problems". Also, make sure you have PHP and MySQL error reporting enabled. Lastly, avoid the JavaScript stuff for now, it hides problems. Just echo or var_dump.

Comment: Sometimes it inserts correctly, most times it inserts twice. That's my only challenge actually. I also tried your fix by reporting errors using || ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);  ||  and also disabled the javascript alert but no error was displayed. I'd appreciate it if you could look at the code a little closer. Thank you

Comment: There are no obvious syntax or coding issues here. You're going to have to do some troubleshooting, like checking the server log to see if requests are being sent twice.

Comment: I checked the error logs and there's no problem

Comment: Please edit the question with any and all updates, rather than just adding to the list of comments. The "edit" button is just under the little blue "php" tag at the end of your question. Thanks.

Comment: What other debugging have you done? How are requests to this script triggered on the client side? e.g. perhaps you have some users resubmitting the form unwittingly, or perhaps you have some dodgy logic triggering extra AJAX requests or duplicating the data being sent, or something. Have you inspected the contents of `$_POST` for each request, and checked there are definitely no more requests being logged than you expected? There's nothing obvious in the PHP code which would cause the same data to be inserted multiple times - I suspect it's an issue elsewhere in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I had included a script to reload the page in my header hence the double inserting, upon discarding the script, my problem was fixed. Thank you all for helping me with my challenge